# Yarn Workspaces is hoisting modules that exist in only one workspace

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to implement yarn workspaces + lerna into my project. I have a simple structure:

```
--package.json
--node_modules/
--@app/
    |--client/
       |--package.json
       |--node_modules/
    |--server/
       |--package.json
       |--node_modules/
    |--db/
       |--package.json
       |--node_modules/
```

Where client/ is a **React-Native** app. I am aware of the gotchas in react-native, and have modified my root `/package.json` as follows:

```
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "@app/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**",
    ]
  },
```

As I understand it, this should prevent react native itself, plus any of react-native's dependencies from being hoisted. However, what I am experiencing is that react-native libraries like `react-native-linear-gradient` and `react-native-reanimated` (which exist solely in `client/package.json`) are being hoisted and installed at the root level `node_modules`. It is not even just native modules that are hoisted. Javascript dependencies are also being hoisted:

- native-base
- react-redux
- @apollo
- styled-components

Of course, the `nohoist` option should not even come into play here, since these modules are only ever used within the `client/` directory.

So then why would they be hoisted to the root?

For good measure, I have deleted the `yarn.lock` files in each of my workspaces, keeping only the root level one. After running `lerna clean` and `rm -rf node_modules`, I have run `yarn install` at the root level.

Interestingly, this install is *very* long (3-5 min). It even takes around 20s just to remove the root level `node_modules`. I'm not at all sure if this is normal with yarn workspaces+lerna.

### Additional Details

yarn version - 1.22.10

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> what I am experiencing is that react-native libraries like react-native-linear-gradient and react-native-reanimated (which exist solely in client/package.json) are being hoisted and installed at the root level node_modules

That's the intended behaviour, since they are not dependencies of `react-native`. You would have to specify quite a bit of patterns like:

```
"nohoist": [
  "**/react-native",
  "**/react-native/**",
  "**/react-native*",
  "**/native-base",
  "**/react-redux",
  // OMG...
]
```

to match them all...

I actually would recommend to simply add this:

```
"workspaces": { "nohoist": "**" }
```

to the `client/package.json` file.

This will cause *all* dependencies of the `client` package to be installed in `client/node_modules` – as if it was a standalone React Native project that doesn't have a Workspace at its parent.

Otherwise you would have to be constantly on guard when adding new packages in general (and **especially** native module packages) – did your `nohoist` pattern reflect all the libraries you have added?

Also, there are issues with autolinking and hoisting.

On a more general and pathetic note, I'd say Yarn Workspaces' deduplication feature is overrated. It reduces disk space usage only marginally, and it might be simpler to just `nohoist` everything and use Workspaces only for the case where it really shines – for easy local package linking.

Comment: so in this case, would the `clients/` directory have its own `yarn.lock`?

Comment: @Tycholiz No! It will all work as a normal workspace, but all of `client`s dependencies' sources will be located in `client/node_modules`

Comment: Remember to use yarn

Comment: "It reduces disk space usage only marginally" - it can reduce the time it takes to install packages by a huge amount (50% in my case). In cases where yarn is being ran frequently in CI it can be a huge deal.

For us we have 3 react native apps in a monorepo, each with the same package.json, so doing no hoist is very wasteful

Although - nohoisting everything can solve a lot of problems